# Pasting chart fails when outside of viewable screen area

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Whilst this proven method has worked for people and works for me in the general sense, I receive "Error 1004: Method 'Paste' of object '_Chart' failed." However, on the 5th iteration of the loop this method failure occurs. I have tried isolating each component of the Array and the 6th and 7th elements always fail, but when the 5th element is used in isolation or as the starting point of the loop it succeeds. I have also tried clearing the clipboard at different stages of the process to see if that helps and tested the object property of the "cht" object.

```
Sub PicturesCopy()

'Define path variables
Path = "C:\Users\khill\Documents\Macro Tests\"
PathSC = Path & "Master Cockpit\"
FileMCP = "Master_Daily sales cockpit.xlsm"
Set wbMCP = Workbooks(FileMCP)

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim rngList, fileList As Variant


rngList = Array("B2:Y19", "B22:U39", "B43:O58", "B61:R76", "B81:J96", "B101:AD118", "B122:V139")
fileList = Array("Fig 1a", "Fig 1b", "Fig 2a", "Fig 2b", "Fig 2c", "Fig 3a", "Fig 3b")


For x = 0 To UBound(rngList)

    'Application.CutCopyMode = True

    With wbMCP.Worksheets("Graphs")
        Debug.Print rngList(x)
        Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = .Range(rngList(x))
        Debug.Print x
        rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    End With



    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    Set cht = wbMCP.Worksheets("Pictures").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)

    cht.Name = "PicChart"

    With cht

        .Chart.Paste
        Debug.Print fileList(x)
        .Chart.Export "C:\Users\khill\Documents\Macro Tests\Pics\" & fileList(x) & ".jpg"
        .Delete


    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

    Set cht = Nothing
    Set rgExp = Nothing

Next x





End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem. The charts have to be contained within the viewable screen to be pasted by the clipboard. so you can either zoom out (not ideal because the images are saved small and therefore pixelated) or zoom to the new Chart area/select the position where the chart object is placed in the first place. My solution was to zoom to the range. Adjusted Code is below. Hope this helps someone else :)

```
Sub PicturesCopy()

'Define path variables
Path = "C:\Users\khill\Documents\Macro Tests\"
PathSC = Path & "Master Cockpit\"
FileMCP = "Master_Daily sales cockpit.xlsm"
Set wbMCP = Workbooks(FileMCP)

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim rngList, fileList As Variant


rngList = Array("B2:Y19", "B22:U39", "B43:O58", "B61:R76", "B81:J96", "B101:AD118", "B122:V139")
fileList = Array("Fig 1a", "Fig 1b", "Fig 2a", "Fig 2b", "Fig 2c", "Fig 3a", "Fig 3b")


For x = 0 To UBound(rngList)

    'Application.CutCopyMode = True

    With wbMCP.Worksheets("Graphs")
        Debug.Print rngList(x)
        Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = .Range(rngList(x))
        Debug.Print x
        rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    End With



    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    Set cht = wbMCP.Worksheets("Pictures").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)

    cht.Name = "PicChart"

    'Use ZoomToRange sub to re-size the window as appropriate
    ZoomToRange ZoomThisRange:=Range(rngList(x)), PreserveRows:=True


    With cht

        .Chart.Paste
        Debug.Print fileList(x)
        .Chart.Export "C:\Users\khill\Documents\Macro Tests\Pics\" & fileList(x) & ".jpg"
        .Delete


    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

    Set cht = Nothing
    Set rgExp = Nothing

Next x




End Sub
```

The ZoomToRange macro that is called in the above is as follows:

```
Sub ZoomToRange(ByVal ZoomThisRange As Range, _
    ByVal PreserveRows As Boolean)

'###################################
'This macro resizes the window and''
'zoom properties to be appropriate''
'for our use''''''''''''''''''''''''
'###################################

'Turn alerts and screen updating off
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare variable type
Dim Wind As Window
'Create variable for window
Set Wind = ActiveWindow



'Zooming to specified range set to true
Application.GoTo ZoomThisRange(1, 1), True

'Select the resized range
With ZoomThisRange
    If PreserveRows = True Then
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Select
    Else
        .Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Select
    End If
End With
'Set zoom and visible range to specified range
With Wind
    .Zoom = True
    .VisibleRange(1, 1).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I solved the similar problem by selecting the ChartObject. In the example case that would be by doing cht.Select before cht.Chart.Paste.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a clipboard viewer to verify that the `rgExp.CopyPicture` operation has done what you expect when `Debug.Print x` shows 5 (6th iteration)?

Assuming you are using some version of Windows, there are some tips on how to view clipboard here, depending on version:

**View & Manage Clipboard In Windows 10 / 8 / 7**
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-clipboard-manager-viewer

Comment: No I haven't yet but will try that directly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 at work and unfortunately can't install anything new, so not sure this will help. However, I just adjusted the code to Paste images into the respective ranges in the "Pictures" sheet and they all pasted for each iteration of the loop. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Someone also suggested time was an issue and I used Application.Wait to eliminate this as the root cause. I am now testing in a completely new Workbook and getting the same failure at an earlier point in the process, suggesting the issue is not the content of the images and rather something else.